# Why is Graphene Such a Good Conductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conductors, graphene

I'm doing a paper on graphene, and in the intro I need to elaborate why it has drawn so much attention. Well, I'm stuck on the good conductivity! Why is graphene such a good conductor? Does it relate to the relativistic spectrum around K? And if not, what practical consequences does the last have? I've been looking for answers in review papers but can't find anything that tackles these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbon has a valency of $4$, but in a graphene sheet each carbon atom only covalently bonds to $3$ other carbon atoms. This leaves $1$ electron free to delocalize, giving a semimetal conduction band. Graphite is also a good conductor; due to the material's banding, the delocalized electrons can move between individual sheets.

Comment: So it has more to do with the fact that it is a two-dimensional material and therefore the delocalized electron isn't stuck on a bond?

Comment: @RichHardFineMan You'd be amazed how many chemical properties result from geometry. Why is epoxyethane unstable? Because bond lengths determine small bond angles that accentuate electron pair repulsion.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RichHardFineMan welcome to the site. The rule is if the answer is useful  for you, an approval is given by hitting the ^  sign on the left of the answer to give points to the user answering.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware, but it says that I have to have 15 reputation to do that.